# Run console app(MediaInfo.exe), and put output to variable

Tags: powershell, mediainfo

CMD:

```
MediaInfo.exe -h
```

Output - **help information**

Ps:

```
$res = MediaInfo.exe -h
```

$res - **help information** (ok)

CMD:

```
MediaInfo.exe --Output=Audio;%StreamKindPos%^|%Language/String%^|%Title% video.mkv
```

Output - **audio information**

ps:

```
$res = MediaInfo.exe '--Output=Audio;%StreamKindPos%^|%Language/String%^|%Title% video.mkv'
```

$res - **Usage: "MediaInfo [-Options...] FileName1 [Filename2...]"
"MediaInfo --Help" for displaying more information** (wrong output)

How to launch a console application correctly from powershell? Maybe I need to escape something in the parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options and file path is a two parameters, and you should pass them as two parameters:

```
$res = MediaInfo.exe "--Output=Audio;%StreamKindPos%^|%Language/String%^|%Title%" "video.mkv"
```